# TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined in nodejs

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb

I am developing a register form using Angular6, mongodb and nodejs. There I have written a post method to save users in mongodb if the user does not exist in the database. When the users are added to the database, an email should be sent to user and user should redirect to another view. That view is also in the earlier html and it shows only when the result is success.If the  email name is already in the db it should show an error message. I have used the default error message in password. strategy-options.ts for the error message for existing users.But when I try to add a new user it does not navigate to the next view and the terminal shows the following error message. 
**TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined**
"....node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:132"

Here is my save method.

```
router.post('/signup', function(req,  next) {
   console.log("Came into register function.");

    var newUser = new userInfo({
     firstName : req.body.firstName,
     lastName : req.body.lastName,
     rank : req.body.lastName,
     mobile :  req.body.lastName,
     email : req.body.email,
     userName : req.body.userName,
     password : req.body.password,
     status : req.body.status
    });

    newUser.save(function (err, user,res) {
      console.log("Came to the save method");
      if (err){
        console.log(user.email);
        res.send(err);
        return res;
      } 
      else{
        var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
          service: 'Gmail',
          auth: {
            user: 't36@gmail.com',
            pass: '12345'
          }
        });

        var mailOptions = {
          from: 'reg@demo.com',
          to: newUser.email,
          subject: 'Send mails',
          text: 'That was easy!'
        };
        console.log("This is the user email"+" "+newUser.email);
        transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
          if (error) {
            console.log("Error while sending email"+" "+error);
          } else {
            console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
          }

        });
        console.log("success");
        return res.send("{success}");

      }

    });

});
```

Here is my register method in register.component.ts file.

```
register(): void {
        this.errors = this.messages = [];
        this.submitted = true;

        this.service.register(this.strategy, this.user).subscribe((result: NbAuthResult) => {
            this.submitted = false;
            if (result.isSuccess()) {
                this.messages = result.getMessages();
                this.isShowConfirm = true;
                this.isShowForm = false;
            }
            else {
                this.errors = result.getErrors();
            }

            const redirect = result.getRedirect();
            if (redirect) {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    return this.router.navigateByUrl(redirect);
                }, this.redirectDelay);
            }
            this.cd.detectChanges();

        });
    }
```

I have tried so many methods in internet to solve this. But still did not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all node js router consist of 3 params `req, res, next` you miss out the res param, in your case the `next` behave as the `res` params.
Secondly Model.save only returns error and saved data there no res parameter in it. So the finally code will look like this

```
router.post('/signup', function(req, res, next) {
 console.log("Came into register function.");
 var newUser = new userInfo({
   firstName : req.body.firstName,
   lastName : req.body.lastName,
   rank : req.body.lastName,
   mobile :  req.body.lastName,
   email : req.body.email,
   userName : req.body.userName,
   password : req.body.password,
   status : req.body.status
 });

newUser.save(function (err, user) {
  console.log("Came to the save method");
  if (err){
    console.log(user.email);
    res.send(err);
    return res;
  } 
  else{
    var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
      service: 'Gmail',
      auth: {
        user: 't36@gmail.com',
        pass: '12345'
      }
    });

    var mailOptions = {
      from: 'reg@demo.com',
      to: newUser.email,
      subject: 'Send mails',
      text: 'That was easy!'
    };
    console.log("This is the user email"+" "+newUser.email);
    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
      if (error) {
        console.log("Error while sending email"+" "+error);
      } else {
        console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
      }

    });
    console.log("success");
    return res.send("{success}");
  }
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve this same error message **TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined** in my rest api application, I found that I missed the valid syntax `res.status(200).send(data)` or `res.send(data)`. Although I found the data in my console.
[image]

```
module.exports.getUsersController = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    // Password is not allowed to pass to client section
    const users = await User.find({}, "-password");

    const resData = {
      users,
      success: {
        title: 'All Users',
        message: 'All the users info are loaded successfully.'
      }
    }
    console.log(resData)
    // This is not correct
    // return res.status(200).res.send(resData);
    // It should be
    return res.status(200).send(resData);

  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
    return res.status(500).send(err);
  }
};
```

When you use `res.status()`, you have to use `.send()` following this, not use `res` again.

I think it will be helpful for developers who did the same mistake as well. Happy developers!